# Registering event in constructor OpenLayers 3 map?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I need register event in constructor of map.

How can I do that?

Is there something like similar?

```
  var view = new ol.View({
    eventListeners: {
        "change:resolution": function () { console.log("test"); },
    }
});
```

I won't use view.on('change:resolution').

Comment: whats wrong with `view.on('change:resolution'`??????

Comment: Nothing, but in the code are places where is set new view with different parameters. And I try to set all in constructor.

Comment: No, no way at all.

Comment: OK thanks. I have to find another approach.